# Defining a macro as comma (to separate arguemnts with that marco) works properly in functions arguments but not in other macros

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I come up with a small example of the problem

Assume I have this macro

```c
#define and ,
```

And I use it like `sum(a and b)` which should be expanded to `sum(a, b)`.

My problem here is that if `sum` is defined by a macro the usage example encounters a `too few arguments ...` error.

Another problem that I think probably will be related and I guess would be solved by the same trick, is when I define an empty macro and place it between function name and argument list. For example

```c
#define of
```

Now when I use `sum of(1, 2)`, the compiler treats `sum` as a function and if it is a macro, then, linker throws an `undefined reference` error.

```c
#define of
#define sum(a, b) a + b

int main()
{
    sum of(a, b); // undefined reference to `sum'
}
```

Comment: `and` is a keyword, redefining keywords is undefined behavior.

Comment: I strongly advice not to use this kind of pointless macro trickery.

Comment: Besides this, `#define sum(a, b) a + b` should be `#define sum(a, b) ((a) + (b))`.

Comment: If you continue down the path of using macros to define your own language, you'll get a useless mess that no-one can easily follow, and that debuggers have trouble working with too.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? If you want  to invent a different language then you better start from scratch rather than misusing the preprocessor. If you want to write C++ or C then its not clear what those macros are good for

Comment: @Jabberwocky @463035818_is_not_a_number
I know it's is a little bit pointless, but I was trying to define a `foreach` loop for a linked list which is still silly, but at least less.

Comment: @Odeaxcsh Well, don't.  Your heading down a rabbit hole here.

Comment: @Paul Sanders Yup got it =). thanks

Comment: Don't try to transform C into another language. All your future readers (including yourself in two weeks, months, or years) will be confused. Use the language as it is intended.

Comment: "I was trying to define a foreach loop for a linked list" no macros are needed to do this

Comment: "Foreach" is a somewhat pointless higher level concept anyway. In case you are using C++, I suppose the C++11 range-based for loop might be the feature you are trying to invent?

Comment: Right, macro expansion does not support what you are trying to do (which is one reason to not do it). What is your intended question: why it doesn't work or how you can make equivalent functionality work?

Comment: If you want a "foreach loop", implement the necessary bits to enable standard range loops; it doesn't require a lot. Also, if you ask about your actual problem rather than your proposed solution, you might even get something that works. (See [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: `and` is not a keyword. The keywords are listed in C 2018 6.4.1 1, and `and` is not among them. The standard header `<iso646.h>` defines `and` as a macro that is replaced by `&&`. In the absence of inclusion of that header, programs may use `and` for other purposes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil cppref seems to be a bit unclear about that. I had to check and you are right. `and` is not a keyword in C++, but it is reserved. I guess you mean C, and I think it is different in C++, where it is reserved

Comment: @Odeaxcsh: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two different languages. Pick one language and delete the other tag.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Yes I didn't notice that, thanks, I removes the C++ tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue with `and` macro is that `a and b` is identified as macro argument before replacing `and` with `,` happens.

> #### 6.10.3.1 Argument substitution
>
> 1. **After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument
>    substitution takes place.** A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded by a # or ## prepro-
>    cessing token or followed by a ## preprocessing token (see below), is replaced by the corresponding
>    argument after all macros contained therein have been expanded. **Before being substituted, each
>    argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the
>    preprocessing file;** no other preprocessing tokens are available.

Your second problem is similar but not related. After `of` is expanded, it is too late to expand `sum` because it is no longer scanned by the preprocessor:

> #### 6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement
>
> 1. After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and # and ## processing has
>    taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. **The resulting preprocessing token
>    sequence is then rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file**, for
>    more macro names to replace.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. What is the name of the document which you quoted from?

Comment: @Odeaxcsh It's from C standard draft (C17). It's pretty close to actual C11 and C18 standard documents.